# How to get mathematica to display scientific notation to the correct amount of significant figures?

Tags: output-formatting

I need to evaluate this expression in scientific notation to four decimal places: 
((10*((10.8*10^3)/300)^(1/2))+4)^(1/3)

I used Scientificform[expr,precision] but mathematica is displaying my answer as '4.", how can I fix this?

Comment: The value (caculated with `$MachinePrecision` digits) is 3.9999999999999996. Do you want to see 4.000 ?

Comment: in that case : `NumberForm[((10*((10.8*10^3)/300)^(1/2))+4)^(1/3),{4,4}]`

Comment: Keep an eye out for Around, a new function coming in the next* release that will do exactly what you want, and with unit compatibility.

See [this](https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?v=2131) video with [this](http://wac.36f4.edgecastcdn.net/0036F4/pub/www.wolfram.com/technology-conference/2017/JoseMartinGarciaUncertaintyRepresentationandPropagation.nb) documentation for details on the solution to your question for the future.

•based on Stephen Wolfram's design livestreams